# Would DB performance be better to store all responses from the user in the same row or multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, datatable

I need to create a table to store a user’s responses to a question and they can have up to 12 responses, what table structure would work best. I have created 2 options but if you have a better Idea I am open for suggestions.

Table 1 (Store each answer in a new row)
UserId

- QuestionId
- Answer Number
- Answer

Table 2(Store all answers in one row)

- UserId
- QuestionId
- Answer 1
- Answer2
- Answer3
- Answer4
- Answer5
- Answer6
- Answer7
- Answer8
- Answer9
- Answer10
- Answer11
- Answer12

Comment: How many users? What sort of transaction rate are you expecting? If it's a low-use database, it won't really matter.

Comment: This is going to be a high activity table. starting off 1000 users.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify this, the UserId and QuestionId are foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely store the answers as separate records.

If you store the answers in one record, you will have data (the answer number) in the field names, so that breaks the first normal form. This is a sign of a really bad database design.

With the answers in separate records it's easier to access the data. Consider for example that you want to get the last answer for each question and user. This is very easy if you have the answers as separate records, but very complicated if you have them in a single record.

Answer (score 1):

giving each answer its own row would better. so i would recommend going with your idea for table 1. that way if you want to up the limit from 12 to say 20 you do not need to add a new column and you can count responses easier.

Comment: You didn't say why it's better.

Comment: -1 It is **not** better according to OP's question - it's slower! He didn't ask if for the best design, he asked for the *fastest* design

Comment: if he goes with option 2 as you suggest then when a user adds a response he has to evaluate the data in each column to decide where to store the next question.in addition, to determine how many total responses any 1 user has at a time he has to test contents of each column. its also a waste if a user has no responses at all

Answer (score 1):

The answer is option 2 will perform better, because you only need one I/O operation to retrieve all answers. I once built a data warehouse with a similar "wide" design, and it performed amazingly well.

...but typically, performance shouldn't be the *only* consideration.

From a database design point of view, it's better to use one row per answer.
This is because:

- adding columns (to cater for more answers) involves a schema change (much harder), but adding rows does not
- rows are scaleable (what if someone had 1000 answers - are you going to 1000 columns?)
- queries are easier - you must actually *name each answer* if stored in columns, but with rows you name only the answer column and use SQL to pull everything together

Unless raw speed is your stand out goal, prefer option 2 (more rows) over option 1 (more columns).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want redundancy and unnecessary/unused columns. From proper db design, you should definitely go with option one. This is a more normalized, and will add value if you decide to scale it any time later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend neither design.

All answers in one row breaks first normal form.

I'd have a Question table, a User table, and an Answer table.  A User could be given many Questions; there's one Answer per Question.

Answer (score 1):

From a true performance perspective it depends (from a good database design perspective it's a no brainer, multiple rows is the way to go).

If all your answers fit within a single page and you're seeking that row using a clustered index it is probably going to be slightly faster with solution 2.  Your tree would have less leaves making the search of a smaller dataset.  You also avoid the Cartesian that comes with a join.

Solution 1 will be a little faster if you have page splits.  As long as the join column is indexed of course.

Though the in the end minor performance increase you could get with option 1 over option 2 would probably be insignificant compared to the maintenance costs of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

The first option would need to store the user-id multiple times too.
I would go for the second option, especially if you can put a hard limit on it such as 12.
This also requires only a single write operation for the database.
What are these 12 things ... months?